# How to implement gyroscope sensor in android?

Tags: android, sensors, gyroscope

I'm trying to write the simplest implementation of the gyroscope (only to log the orientation of the screen when it's changed). Could someone provide a simple example of this?

---

This is what I'm trying right now:

```
public class LessonFiveGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements SensorEventListener 
        {
        private LessonFiveRenderer mRenderer;

        public LessonFiveGLSurfaceView(Context context) 
        {
            super(context); 
            System.out.println("test");
        }
        @Override  
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)  
        {  
            //output the Roll, Pitch and Yawn values  
            System.out.println("Orientation X (Roll) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[2]) +"\n"+  
                       "Orientation Y (Pitch) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[1]) +"\n"+  
                       "Orientation Z (Yaw) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[0]));  
        }
```

However I'm getting error: "The type LessonFiveGLSurfaceView must implement the inherited abstract method SensorEventListener.onAccuracyChanged(Sensor, int)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a class I came up with to absract the use a Gyroscope sensor in android it will smooth the input data a little, as well as correct orientation output for tablet and phone which doesn't have the same natural orientation (phone are in portrait while tablet are in landscape):

```
/**
* Uses the sensor API to determine the phones orientation.
* Registering for events from the accelerator and the magnetometer (compass)
* a rotation matrix is computed. This matrix can be used to rotate an
* OpenGL scene.
*/
public class PhoneGyroscope  implements SensorEventListener{
private static final String TAG = PhoneGyroscope.class.getSimpleName();
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private float[] mAccelGravityData = new float[3];
private float[] mGeomagneticData = new float[3];
private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] bufferedAccelGData = new float[3];
private float[] bufferedMagnetData = new float[3];

public PhoneGyroscope(Context context) {
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
}

public void start() {
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME );
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME );
}

public void stop() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

private void loadNewSensorData(SensorEvent event) {
    final int type = event.sensor.getType();
    if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        //Smoothing the sensor data a bit
        mAccelGravityData[0]=(mAccelGravityData[0]*2+event.values[0])*0.33334f;
        mAccelGravityData[1]=(mAccelGravityData[1]*2+event.values[1])*0.33334f;
        mAccelGravityData[2]=(mAccelGravityData[2]*2+event.values[2])*0.33334f;
    }
    if (type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        //Smoothing the sensor data a bit
        mGeomagneticData[0]=(mGeomagneticData[0]*1+event.values[0])*0.5f;
        mGeomagneticData[1]=(mGeomagneticData[1]*1+event.values[1])*0.5f;
        mGeomagneticData[2]=(mGeomagneticData[2]*1+event.values[2])*0.5f;

        float x = mGeomagneticData[0];
        float y = mGeomagneticData[1];
        float z = mGeomagneticData[2];
        double field = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
        if (field>25 && field<65){
            Log.e(TAG, "loadNewSensorData : wrong magnetic data, need a recalibration field = " + field);
        }
    }
}


private void rootMeanSquareBuffer(float[] target, float[] values) {

    final float amplification = 200.0f;
    float buffer = 20.0f;

    target[0] += amplification;
    target[1] += amplification;
    target[2] += amplification;
    values[0] += amplification;
    values[1] += amplification;
    values[2] += amplification;

    target[0] = (float) (Math
            .sqrt((target[0] * target[0] * buffer + values[0] * values[0])
                    / (1 + buffer)));
    target[1] = (float) (Math
            .sqrt((target[1] * target[1] * buffer + values[1] * values[1])
                    / (1 + buffer)));
    target[2] = (float) (Math
            .sqrt((target[2] * target[2] * buffer + values[2] * values[2])
                    / (1 + buffer)));

    target[0] -= amplification;
    target[1] -= amplification;
    target[2] -= amplification;
    values[0] -= amplification;
    values[1] -= amplification;
    values[2] -= amplification;
}


/*
 * Tablets have LANDSCAPE as default orientation, so screen rotation is 0 or 180 when the orientation is LANDSCAPE, and smartphones have PORTRAIT.
 * I use the next code to difference between tablets and smartphones:
 */
public static int getScreenOrientation(Display display){
    int orientation;

    if(display.getWidth()==display.getHeight()){
        orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
    }else{ //if width is less than height than it is portrait
        if(display.getWidth() < display.getHeight()){
            orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }else{ // if it is not any of the above it will definitly be landscape
            orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        }
    }   
    return orientation;
}

private void debugSensorData(SensorEvent event) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("--- SENSOR ---");
    builder.append("\nName: ");
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    builder.append(sensor.getName());
    builder.append("\nType: ");
    builder.append(sensor.getType());
    builder.append("\nVendor: ");
    builder.append(sensor.getVendor());
    builder.append("\nVersion: ");
    builder.append(sensor.getVersion());
    builder.append("\nMaximum Range: ");
    builder.append(sensor.getMaximumRange());
    builder.append("\nPower: ");
    builder.append(sensor.getPower());
    builder.append("\nResolution: ");
    builder.append(sensor.getResolution());

    builder.append("\n\n--- EVENT ---");
    builder.append("\nAccuracy: ");
    builder.append(event.accuracy);
    builder.append("\nTimestamp: ");
    builder.append(event.timestamp);
    builder.append("\nValues:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.values.length; i++) {
        // ...
        builder.append("   [");
        builder.append(i);
        builder.append("] = ");
        builder.append(event.values[i]);
        builder.append("\n");
    }

    Log.d(TAG, builder.toString());
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* Sensor Processing/Rotation Matrix
 * Each time a sensor update happens the onSensorChanged method is called. 
 * This is where we receive the raw sensor data.
 * First of all we want to take the sensor data from the accelerometer and magnetometer and smooth it out to reduce jitters.
 * From there we can call the getRotationMatrix function with our smoothed accelerometer and magnetometer data.
 * The rotation matrix that this outputs is mapped to have the y axis pointing out the top of the phone, so when the phone is flat on a table facing north, it will read {0,0,0}.
 * We need it to read {0,0,0} when pointing north, but sitting vertical. To achieve this we simply remap the co-ordinates system so the X axis is negative.
 * The following code example shows how this is acheived. 
 */
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE) {
        return;
    }

    loadNewSensorData(event);
    int type=event.sensor.getType();

    if (mAccelGravityData != null && mGeomagneticData != null) {

        if ((type==Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) || (type==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)) {
            rootMeanSquareBuffer(bufferedAccelGData, mAccelGravityData);
            rootMeanSquareBuffer(bufferedMagnetData, mGeomagneticData);
            if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, bufferedAccelGData, bufferedMagnetData)){

                Display display = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
                int orientation = getScreenOrientation(display);
                int rotation = display.getRotation();

                boolean dontRemapCoordinates  = (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) ||
                        (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) ||
                        (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT && rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) ||
                        (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT && rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270);

                if( !dontRemapCoordinates){
                                    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(
                                            mRotationMatrix,
                                            SensorManager.AXIS_Y, 
                                            SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
                                            mRotationMatrix);
                }
                debugSensorData(event); 
            }
        }       
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It's not a problem, but why do you use accelerometer, but not a gyroscope?

Comment: Because gyroscopes weren't a standard on all android devices at the time of this response, only added since android 4.0.3

Comment: and why accelerometer + magnetic_field, if you just need accelerometer?

Comment: This answer is very good implementation of accelometer + magnetic field sensor = compass but not the answer for gyroscope. And should not be accepted answer for "How to implement gyroscope sensor in android?" question. It does not matter if devices have gyroscope or not. [Answer for gyroscope implementation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro)

Answer (score 1):

The SensorEventListener interface has 2 functions.  You need to implement both.  You can have the function do nothing, but you still need to implement it.

Comment: check my edit, I implemented both functions but I don't get any logs when I rotate the device.

Comment: Did you register the class as a sensor listener with the sensor manager?